# scale bokeh heatmap plot size with cells

Tags: bokeh, heatmap

I am trying to generate a rectangular plot using Bokeh. I want the plot to set the the dimensions such that as I increase elements on either x or y axis, the cells cover the entire plot.

Here is what I am trying to do:

````
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file 

from bokeh.palettes import Reds

data_dict={'state':['New York','New Mexico','New York','New Mexico'],'feature':['poverty','poverty','unemployment','unemployment'],'color':=[Reds[9][0],Reds[9][1],Reds[9][2],Reds[9][3]}

p = figure(title="testing",tools="hover", toolbar_location=None,x_range=data_dict['feature'], y_range=data_dict['state'])

p.rect('feature','state',source=data_dict,
color='color',width=1,height=1)

p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "10pt"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/3

show(p)```

Eliminate all the whitespace in the plot.
````

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking for a heatmap similar to this one in Bokeh's examples:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/categorical.html?highlight=heatmap

I fiddled with your code a little bit and came up with something similar. The code didn't run exactly as posted, so I'm not sure what you saw, but you would have needed separate lists for range labels (since there's repetition in the data_dict lists).

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Reds
import numpy as np

data_dict = {
                'state': ['New York', 'New York', 'New Mexico', 'New Mexico'],
                'feature': ['poverty', 'unemployment', 'poverty', 'unemployment'],
                'colors': [Reds[9][0], Reds[9][1],
                           Reds[9][2], Reds[9][3]]
            }
x_labels = ['poverty', 'unemployment']
y_labels = ['New York', 'New Mexico']


p = figure(title="testing",tools="hover", toolbar_location=None, x_range=x_labels, y_range=y_labels)

p.rect('feature', 'state', source=data_dict,
       color='colors', width=1, height=1)

p.grid.grid_line_color = None
p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "10pt"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = np.pi/3

show(p)
```